# TCP packet never arrives at socket?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to make a peer-to-peer file transfer program, but I'm having some issues with the initial exchange of "here's what pieces I have!" between newly arriving peers and those who were already there.

Essentially, once the newly arrived peer (who we'll call B) establishes a TCP connection (always successfully) with one that was already there (who we'll call A), it sends an array representing what pieces of the file it has. This is successful most of the time, but for the 3rd, 4th, or 5th peer to join in a 6-peer session, A will send its array but B won't receive it, sometimes. Typically one or two of the arrays will go missing. However, they go on to exchange pieces and otherwise communicate just fine--it's just that now B will never know if A has pieces it received before B joined.

As far as infrastructure goes, each connection between peers is in its own thread. Only that thread ever reads from or writes to the socket connecting them. There is a LOT of communication going on at any given time among all the threads, but within each thread it's always to and from the one socket; though there is a "thread wrangler" who does some additional protocol management (no reading or writing to the socket, though), none of that protocol is really in play when a peer just connects.

Is there any reason why this might be, or ways to fix it? Relevant code below. It should be noted that this is literally the ONLY piece of communication to go missing. Everything else is accounted for.

Right after the connection is established:

```
locked = true; //a volatile boolean
byte[] pieces = this.makePacket(piecesArray)
this.out.write(pieces);
locked = false
```

'locked', if true, will prevent a peer from making any updates to its array until it is false again. This was to solve the issue of the array being sent not being completely updated. 'locked' is only evaluated for truthfulness (to go into a while loop) when a piece update message is received.

In the main piece receival loop:

```
byte [] sizeField = new byte[4];
this.in.read(sizeField);
int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(sizeField).getInt();

byte[] packet = new byte[size];
int bytesRead = this.in.read(packet);
while (bytesRead < size)
{
     bytesRead = bytesRead + this.in.read(packet, bytesRead, size-bytesRead);
}

if(packet.getMessage() == "Pieces")
{
     //store em -- if the piece array exchange message doesn't arrive, the code in here never runs
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: a new user (B) always sends its pieces list to the first user (A), even if there are more than one users already ?

Comment: Upon first entering the application, a user will get the piece lists of every other user currently running. A represents any pre existing user, while B represents the newest one. Upon starting the application, B will reach out to and connect with everyone who came before it and exchange piece lists with them and then wait (in a different thread) to acept new incoming connections.

Comment: Can you use Wireshark to find out if the data is actually making it to the wire?  Then you know which end is failing.